# Parsing XML Feeds

Tags: java, solr, lucene, xml-parsing, nutch

I want to parse RSS feeds of sites and want to fetch the content ( e.g article) and want to put them into the database. Later i also want to index them based on the search keywords. Can anyone please tell how to proceed? What tools are best to use for this ? 
I searched on Apache lucene, solr and apache nutch. But still i am not clear how to implement it in programming language such as java. 
Can anyone please give more details about the implementation.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I'd have a read through [Java API for XML Processing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/index.html).

Next, I'd become familiar with some of the networking APIs...

- [Custom Networking](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/index.html), in particular, [Working with URLs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/index.html)
- [Apache HTTP Components](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/) (nb. This might be a little advance, but I've found it useful)

I'd also become familiar with [xPath](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/default.asp) and [How xPath Works](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/xslt/xpath.html), this will be useful for finding parts of the documents you are interested in.

Next, I'd become [JDBC(TM) Database Access](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/index.html)

That should just about cover the basics.

Once you have a basic idea of the technologies, you'll need to think about the design.  I separate it element into it's own project.

Deal with downloading, parsing, sorting and inserting the data into the database as one project.

Deal with searching and retrieval in another.

This will highlight the overlapping areas and show you where you need to provide common libraries.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am looking into the links that you mentioned.